# Clojure - Loop Variables - Immutability

Tags: loops, clojure, immutability

I am trying to learn functional programming in Clojure. Many functional programming tutorials begin with the benefits of immutability, and one common example is the loop variable in imperative-style languages. In that respect, how does Clojure's `loop-recur` differ from them? For example:

```
(defn factorial [n]
  (loop [curr-n n curr-f 1]
    (if (= curr-n 1)
      curr-f
      (recur (dec curr-n) (* curr-f curr-n)))))
```

Isn't `curr-n` and `curr-f` mutable values similar to loop variable in imperative-style languages?

Comment: In terms of mental model, think of `recur` as rebinding the names to new values -- the values are still immutable, and if you stored one of those values somewhere (in an atom, &c), it won't change just because `recur` happens to rebind the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thumbnail points out, using `loop-recur` in clojure has the same form and effect as a classic recursive function call.  The only reason it exists is that it is much more efficient than pure recursion.

Since the `recur` can only occur in the tail position, you are guarenteed that the `loop` "variables" will never be needed again. Thus, you don't need to preserve them on the stack, so no stack is used (unlike nested function calls, recursive or not). The end result is that it looks & acts very similarly to an imperative loop in other languages.

The improvement compared to a Java-style `for` loop is that all "variables" are limited to "changing" ***only*** when initialized in the `loop` expression and when updated in the `recur` expression. No changes to the vars can occur in the body of the loop, nor anywhere else (such as embedded function calls which could mutate the loop vars in Java).

Because of these restrictions on where the "loop vars" can be mutated/updated, there are reduced opportunities for a bug to change them unintentionally. The cost of the restrictions is that the loop is not as flexible as a traditional Java-style loop.

As with anything, it is up to you to decide when this cost-benefit tradeoff is a better choice than the other cost-benefit tradeoffs available.  If you want a pure Java-style loop, it is easy to use a clojure `atom` to simulate a Java variable:

```
; Let clojure figure out the list of numbers & accumulate the result
(defn fact-range [n]
  (apply * (range 1 (inc n))))
(spyx (fact-range 4))

; Classical recursion uses the stack to figure out the list of
; numbers & accumulate the intermediate results
(defn fact-recur [n]
  (if (< 1 n)
    (* n (fact-recur (dec n)))
    1))
(spyx (fact-recur 4))

; Let clojure figure out the list of numbers; we accumulate the result
(defn fact-doseq [n]
  (let [result (atom 1) ]
    (doseq [i (range 1 (inc n)) ]
      (swap! result * i))
    @result ))
(spyx (fact-doseq 4))

; We figure out the list of numbers & accumulate the result
(defn fact-mutable [n]
  (let [result (atom 1)
        cnt    (atom 1) ]
    (while (<= @cnt n)
      (swap! result * @cnt)
      (swap! cnt inc))
    @result))
(spyx (fact-mutable 4))

(fact-range 4) => 24
(fact-recur 4) => 24
(fact-doseq 4) => 24
(fact-mutable 4) => 24
```

Even in the last case where we use atoms to emulate mutable variables in Java, at least each place we mutate something it is visibly marked with the `swap!` function, which makes it harder to miss "accidental" mutation.

P.S.  If you wish to use `spyx` it is [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo)

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't `curr-n` and `curr-f` mutable values similar to loop variable in
>   imperative-style languages?

No. You can always rewrite a `loop`-`recur` as a recursive function call. For example, your `factorial` function can be rewritten ...

```
(defn factorial [n]
  ((fn whatever [curr-n curr-f]
     (if (= curr-n 1)
       curr-f
       (whatever (dec curr-n) (* curr-f curr-n))))
   n 1))
```

This is slower and subject to stack-overflow on big numbers.

---

When it comes to the moment of incarnating the call, `recur` overwrites the one-and-only stack frame instead of allocating a new one. This works only if the caller's stack frame is never thereafter referred to - what we call *tail position*.

`loop` is syntactic sugar. I doubt that it is a macro, but it could be. Except that the earlier bindings should be available to the later ones, as in a `let`, though I think this issue is currently moot.

Comment: They are actually mutated in the resulting bytecode if I recall correctly, so it compiles to an actual loop.

Comment: If you paste that into your answer I would totally vote for it